# timepicker.co timepicker only loads on second click on input

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I am using timepicker.co's timepicker on my MEANstack app. My code is as follows:

```
$scope.timePicker = timePicker;

function timePicker() {
    $(function(){
        $('input.timepicker').timepicker({
            timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
            interval: 15,
            minTime: '6',
            maxTime: '10:00pm',
            defaultTime: '6',
            startTime: '10:00',
            dynamic: true,
            dropdown: true,
            scrollbar: true
        });
    })
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="timepicker" class="timepicker" ng-click="timePicker()" value="" placeholder="Please choose a time">
```

The issue is that if I load the page, and click on `.timepicker`, the defaultTime will popup, but I do not see the dropdown list, no matter how many times I click the input. If I click something else on the screen, then click the the `.timepicker` input again, I will see the dropdown.  I am trying to solve this problem, but I don't quite know the issue.  It should also be noted that I am using http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/ for my date picker. Perhaps there is some issue in using both?

Comment: Remove the nested `$(function() {})`

Comment: removed, but didnt help, unfortunately

Comment: The problem, I think, is that you are initializing the plugin inside the handler for the click event, so the plugin doesn't get a chance to respond to that first click. You should call `timepicker()` only once, at some point before the user clicks the input, like when the page loads. Not sure when is the right time to do that in an Angular app, though.